# To which extent are paid alternatives to Apple's Xprotect worth it?

Tags: antivirus, macos

Mac OS X ships with Xprotect, Apple's mechanism to detect and remove malware. System software security holes are patched decently quickly. In a world of fragmented, code-signed, sandboxed apps, what additional advantages would you get from a paid solution like Symantec's or Intego's suite on an actively supported Mac OS? What kind of threats would it successfully detect that the built-in protections wouldn't?